# Replicated cache system to each http servers

Tags: caching

I have setup recently memcached for a PHP site with lot of traffic. Before we used APC but this lacks the possibility to have a unique cache system (invalidating one key on one server doesn't invalidate through the others).

I noticed a big difference when comes to memcached being on same machine as http server or on separated server.

> http+memcached on same server -> 0.06 average time spent to deliver a page
>
> http and memcache on diff servers (but under NAT) -> 0.15 - 0.20 to the deliver a page

So it's a huge difference and I am wondering if won't be better to have the cache system on same machine as http. The additional complexity is the fact the website is served by couple http servers (through a load balancer). So I actually need a cache system with replication, each http server having a cache "copy" and writing the changes only to the "master" (or other approach doing similar things).

There are couple of such systems (couchbase, redis, aso). I think couchbase is not good for this as won't allow connecting to local cache server but rather to the "gate". Redis may work, I am still checking on others.

The main this is: has someone tried this approach to speed up the website? By having on each machine a cache "copy" (kept in synch with the others)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use GigaSpaces XAP solution which is a distributed in memory data grid, but also has an integration with jetty allowing you to deploy your web app and manage it from a single management system. The central distributed data grid (which can be a used as simple cache) can have a local cache on each web container which is kept in sync with the main cache, you don't have to use the jetty integration for it, you can still use your own web container and just create a proxy to the distributed cache with an embedded local cache via code. Or you can also have a fully replicated topology between the web containers without having a main distributed cache and each web container will contain a full copy of the entire cache which will be in sync with the other instances of the web container.

You can read more in:

http://wiki.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/SBP/Web+Service+PU
http://wiki.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/XAP9/Web+Jetty+Processing+Unit+Container
http://wiki.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/XAP9/Client+Side+Caching

Disclaimer: I am a developer working for GigaSpaces.